# impl trait with move method for trait object of same trait

Tags: rust, traits, ownership, trait-objects

I am trying to implement a trait on a boxed trait object of the same trait. I've done this before for trait whose methods take `&self` which works fine, but not `self`.

```rust
// The purpose of this trait is to allow for converting any kind of "group" which might eg be nested tuples like below, and convert it into a flat Vec of Items
trait Group {
    fn into_vec(self) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>>;
}

trait Item: Group {}

// Foo is an Item an can also be made into a group
struct Foo {}
impl Item for Foo {}
impl Group for Foo {
    fn into_vec(self) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>> {
        vec![Box::new(self)]
    }
}

// impl Group for data structures which contain items or other nested structures containing items
impl<A: Group, B: Group> Group for (A, B) {
    fn into_vec(self) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>> {
        let mut new_vec = Vec::new();
        new_vec.extend(self.0.into_vec().into_iter());
        new_vec.extend(self.1.into_vec().into_iter());
        new_vec
    }
}

// Can create a single group fine
fn get_group() -> impl Group {
    (Foo {}, (Foo {}, Foo {}))
}

// Sometimes I might want to return different groups from different braches so need to box them
// However I'm not sure how to implement this. self.into_vec() is an ifinite recursion, and can't deref self either.
impl Group for Box<dyn Group> {
    fn into_vec(self) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>> {
        (*self).into_vec()
    }
}
fn get_group_conditonal(condition: bool) -> impl Group {
    if condition {
        Box::new((Foo {}, (Foo {}, Foo {}))) as Box<dyn Group>
    } else {
        Box::new(Foo {}) as Box<dyn Group>
    }
}
```

I realise that in this particular example I could change `fn get_*()` functions to return `Box<dyn Group>` to solve the problem. However, the rest of the API has functions which take inputs as `impl Group`. If I can't `impl Group for Box<dyn Group>` then this would carry into the rest of the API and require that all functions only take boxed trait objects as inputs, rather than `impl Group`, and I want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: nit: you don't need to call `into_iter()` in the `extend` calls, as [`extend` takes `I: IntoIter<Item = T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend) (`new_vec.extend(self.0.into_vec())` works too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I can come up with and that's [commonly recommended](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-move-self-when-using-dyn-trait/50123) is to have the trait method take `Box<Self>` instead of `Self`:

```rust
trait Group {
    fn into_vec(self: Box<Self>) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>>;
}
```

then

```
impl Group for Box<dyn Group> {
    fn into_vec(self: Box<Self>) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>> {
        (*self).into_vec()
    }
}
```

works as you can see on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8687388a59fa4410c6ab65c92e699fd9) because it doesn't have to deal with a raw `dyn Group`

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented this. It obviously means that anywhere I call .into_vec() I need to Box the receiver if it isn't already, but I'm guessing there is no way around this, and is still much better than not being able to `impl Group for Box<dyn Group>` and having to `Box` Group trait objects everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to pay the cost of boxing for each call, you can have two methods:

```rust
// The purpose of this trait is to allow for converting any kind of "group" which might eg be nested tuples like below, and convert it into a flat Vec of Items
trait Group {
    fn into_vec(self) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>>;
    fn into_vec_dyn(self: Box<Self>) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>>;
}

trait Item: Group {}

// Foo is an Item an can also be made into a group
struct Foo {}
impl Item for Foo {}
impl Group for Foo {
    fn into_vec(self) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>> {
        vec![Box::new(self)]
    }
    
    fn into_vec_dyn(self: Box<Self>) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>> {
        self.into_vec()
    }
}

// impl Group for data structures which contain items or other nested structures containing items
impl<A: Group, B: Group> Group for (A, B) {
    fn into_vec(self) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>> {
        let mut new_vec = Vec::new();
        new_vec.extend(self.0.into_vec().into_iter());
        new_vec.extend(self.1.into_vec().into_iter());
        new_vec
    }
    
    fn into_vec_dyn(self: Box<Self>) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>> {
        self.into_vec()
    }
}

// Can create a single group fine
fn get_group() -> impl Group {
    (Foo {}, (Foo {}, Foo {}))
}

// Sometimes I might want to return different groups from different braches so need to box them
// However I'm not sure how to implement this. self.into_vec() is an ifinite recursion, and can't deref self either.
impl Group for Box<dyn Group> {
    fn into_vec(self) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>> {
        <dyn Group>::into_vec_dyn(self)
    }
    
    fn into_vec_dyn(self: Box<Self>) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>> {
        self.into_vec()
    }
}
```

Of course, writing the method out explicitly for each implementation is... not nice, but we can solve that by splitting the trait:

```rust
trait GroupIntoVecDyn {
    fn into_vec_dyn(self: Box<Self>) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>>;
}

impl<T: Group> GroupIntoVecDyn for T {
    fn into_vec_dyn(self: Box<Self>) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>> {
        self.into_vec()
    }
}

// The purpose of this trait is to allow for converting any kind of "group" which might eg be nested tuples like below, and convert it into a flat Vec of Items
trait Group: GroupIntoVecDyn {
    fn into_vec(self) -> Vec<Box<dyn Item>>;
}
```

Because `GroupIntoVecDyn` is a supertrait of `Group`, you can call its method (even on `dyn Group`), and because of the blanket implementation, you don't actually have to *implement* it.